# Should I upload my email-address and password written in 'settings.py' to Github?

Tags: django, github, email-verification

I have made an email authentication app in django. This app required entering my email address and password in the 'settings.py' file in order to send an email for user verification.

While uploading this project on Github, it would be very dangerous to upload the 'settings.py' file with my email and password written in it.

How should I proceed so that on cloning the repository, the user has to enter his own email and password for the code to run ?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Either create a gitignore file, which would result in the entire file not being tracked, or use environment variables.

Using environment variables in Python: https://able.bio/rhett/how-to-set-and-get-environment-variables-in-python--274rgt5

Answer (score 0):

> Should I upload my email-address and password written in 'settings.py' to Github?

First: no.
Any sensitive information should *not* be uploaded to GitHub.
And use [**gittyleaks**](https://github.com/kootenpv/gittyleaks) to verify you haven't stored any credentials.
Hopefully, the recent [GitHub Token scanning program](https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/about-token-scanning) would pick that up.

Not tracking the file is error-prone (it still could be added by mistake)

You need to use a [third-party source](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3), or using [secrets on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) for instance.